# multithreading - duration of jobs

Tags: operating-systems, cpu, process-scheduling, threads, multi-tasking

" How long will it take for 2 jobs to complete if they're running in parallel, knowing that both have a total of 20 minutes of CPU usage time and 50% IO"

I calculated the CPU usage: `1-0.5²=75%`.
To my understanding, if they're running sequentially, time needed to completion is 80 minutes (each job needs 40 minutes to complete)
therefore time needed to complete both jobs in parallel is `75% * 80 = 60` minutes.

However here is the correct answer:

" CPU utilization is 75%. Thus each one gets 0.375 CPU minute per real time minute. To accumulate 20 minutes of CPU time, a job must run 20/0.375=53.33 minutes. Thus, in parallel, time to completion for both jobs is 53.33 minutes".

I don't get where the 0.375 came from ?

What are CPU minutes ?

Help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

> I don't get where the 0.375 came from ?

If the CPU utilization is 75%, and it's shared equally between two process, each of them gets 37.5%.

> What are CPU minutes?

A CPU-minute is the amount of work done by one CPU in one minute.